# Facebook Query Language get comments with likes and shares greater than 20 on a page

Tags: facebook-fql

I want to fetch comments from a page which have more than 20 likes and 20 shares . How do i do this using FQL

Also is there any FQL query that can search the comment text of the user for example

For example  there is a post

Which phone to buy ?

with some comments like
1) "buy Apple"
2) "buy samsung"

I want to write a query like ...

select comment from that page where likes > 20

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This gets all posts with more than 20 likes on the "Facebook" page, ordered by the descending number of likes:

```
SELECT post_id, source_id, actor_id, message, comments, likes FROM stream 
  WHERE source_id = 20531316728 AND likes.count > 20 ORDER BY likes.count DESC
```

This, of course, is subject to the normal limits of the [stream](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) FQL table.

To search within the comments, you'll need to query the `comments` table with the `post_id` you got from the query above. Something like:

```
SELECT post_id, from_id, time, text FROM comment WHERE post_id = XXXXX 
  AND strpos(text, "buy Apple") >= 0
```

The `strpos` function is pretty limited. You are better off just pulling all the comments into your script and using a more powerful text processing function to find the strings of interest for you.